# Vague job scheduler support for SQL Server on Linux

Tags: sql-server

I’m having some trouble figuring out the kind of support for Linux that the SQL Server 2019 job scheduler has. It’s clear that the job scheduling procedure API, and SQL Server Agent have both been ported to Linux and appear to work. But there are a limited number of *kinds* of job steps supported. These “kinds” of job steps are known as “subsystems” in MS jargon. So when you define a job step, you have to specify what type of task it is.

As documented by Microsoft, these subsystems are ***not*** supported by the Linux port of SQL Server 2019: CmdExec, PowerShell, Replication Distributor, Snapshot, Merge, Queue Reader, SSIS, SSAS, SSRS.

So that’s clear enough, but then what *are* the supported subsystems? There are lots of examples of T-SQL steps that can be defined for a job, but are there others? In particular, can I call out to the OS to run an artbitrary shell script? Is there a definitive list of subsystem types that are supported?

Comment: *"So that’s clear enough, but then what are the supported subsystems?"* The ones that aren't listed as explicitly *not* supported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> what are the supported subsystems?"

The ones that are not *explicitly* listed as **not** supported. From [SQL Server Agent - Subsystems](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/sql-server-agent?view=sql-server-ver15#subsystems):

> #### Subsystems
>
> A subsystem is a predefined object that represents functionality that is available to a job step. Each proxy has access to one or more subsystems. Subsystems provide security because they delimit access to the functionality that is > available to a proxy. Each job step runs in the context of a proxy, except for Transact-SQL job steps. Transact-SQL job steps use the EXECUTE AS command to set the security context to the owner of the Job.
>
> SQL Server defines the subsystems listed in the following table:
>
> | Subsystem name | Description |
> | --- | --- |
> | Microsoft ActiveX Script | Run an ActiveX scripting job step. **Warning** The ActiveX Scripting subsystem will be removed from SQL Server Agent in a future version of MicrosoftSQL Server. Avoid using this feature in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use this feature. |
> | Operating System (**CmdExec**) | Run an executable program. |
> | PowerShell | Run a PowerShell scripting job step. |
> | Replication Distributor | Run a job step that activates the replication Distribution Agent. |
> | Replication Merge | Run a job step that activates the replication Merge Agent. |
> | Replication Queue Reader | Run a job step that activates the replication Queue Reader Agent. |
> | Replication Snapshot | Run a job step that activates the replication Snapshot Agent. |
> | Replication Transaction Log Reader | Run a job step that activates the replication Log Reader Agent. |
> | Analysis Services Command | Run an Analysis Services command. |
> | Analysis Services Query | Run an Analysis Services query. |
> | SSIS package execution | Run an SSIS package. |
>
> > **Note**
> >
> > Because Transact-SQL job steps do not use proxies, there is no SQL Server Agent subsystem for Transact-SQL job steps.
>
> SQL Server Agent enforces subsystem restrictions even when the security principal for the proxy would normally have permission to run the task in the job step. For example, a proxy for a user that is a member of the sysadmin fixed > server role cannot run an SSIS job step unless the proxy has access to the SSIS subsystem, even though the user can run SSIS packages.

For 2019, the correct list of not supported Agent Subsystems is:

- CmdExec
- PowerShell
- Queue Reader
- SSIS
- SSAS
- SSRS

Which leaves the following as supported:

- Microsoft ActiveX Script (*This is due to be removed, so I might be wrong on this, as I would be surprised if Microsoft implemented it on the Linux version.*)
- Replication Distributor
- Replication Merge
- Replication Snapshot
- Replication Transaction Log Reader

Comment: Thanks for the response Lamu. Yes, by deduction you can figure out what should be supported based on their statement of what is *not* supported. And obviously something like calling out to the Windows command line can't be done in a Linux environment. But it's strange to me that they've not explicitly stated somewhere that there is or isn't access to the Linux command line via sh/ksh/bash.

Comment: There no need for an explicit list of supported features, @S.McIntosh  when Microsoft explicitly list what isn't. List both would be redundant and could easily end of with conflicts is one is updated and the other not. One list, of all the unsupported features, tells you exactly what is supported, because it's explicitly not listed as unsupported.

Comment: As for access to the command line, that is explicitly not supported, it states so above in the both CmdExex and Powershell aren't supported; which are the methods SQL Server uses to perform command line functions. Perhaps a Linux feature will one day have bash support, but it is not currently a listed subsystem so it does *not* exist.